# sqlalchemy: Error with commit on session - 'SessionMaker' object has no attribute '_model_changes'

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm new to SqlAlchemy. We were working primarily with Flask, but in a particular case I needed a manual database connection. So I launched a new db connection with something like this:

```
write_engine = create_engine("mysql://user:pass@localhost/db?charset=utf8")
write_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False,
    autoflush=False,bind=write_engine))

nlabel = write_session.query(Label).filter(Label.id==label.id).first() # Works
#Later in code
ms = Message("Some message")
write_session.add(ms) # Works fine
write_session.commit() # Errors out
```

Error looks like "AttributeError: 'SessionMaker' object has no attribute '_model_changes'"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does the Message model look like? If you are using the Flask-Sqlalchemy extension, this may come in handy: https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-sqlalchemy/pull/89

Comment: `write_session` should really be an instance of `Session`, not a `SessionMaker`

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20201809/sqlalchemy-flask-attributeerror-session-object-has-no-attribute-model-chan?lq=1

Answer (score 3):

From [the documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/session.html?highlight=scoped%20session#sqlalchemy.orm.scoped_session) I think you might be missing the initialization of the Session object.

Try:

```
Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False,bind=write_engine))
write_session = Session()
```

It's a shot in the dark- I'm not intimately familiar with SQLAlchemy. Best of luck!

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that you are missing this line:

```
db_session._model_changes = {}
```

Comment: please add some explanation of your solution and how it resolves the problem

Comment: @Philip, because flask attaches a static method for the session. Hence, before commit it checks _model_changes. See flask_sqlclchemy's __init__.py. Here is the function:def session_signal_before_commit(session):
        d = session._model_changes
        if d:
            before_models_committed.send(session.app, changes=d.values())