# FastAPI Python Database connectivity

Tags: python, mysql, rest, post, fastapi

I am new to the FastAPI world, I am creating an API to fetch and post the data to the MySQL database. I followed few link on internet and developed below code

**DatabaseConnection.py**

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

sql_database_url="mysql://root:root@localhost:3306/first_db"

engine=create_engine(sql_database_url)

sessionLocal=sessionmaker(autocommit=False,bind=engine)

base=declarative_base()
```

**MainClass.py**

```
from fastapi import FastAPI,Query,Depends
from sqlalchemy import Column,String,Integer
from typing import Optional,List
from pydantic import BaseModel
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

from DatabaseConnection import engine,sessionLocal,base

app=FastAPI()

class User(base):
    __tablename__="users"
    id=Column(Integer,primary_key=True,index=True)
    name=Column(String(255),unique=True,index=True)

class UserSchema(BaseModel):
    id:int
    name:str

    class Config:
        orm_model=True


base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

@app.post("/create-user")
def createUser(userSchema:UserSchema):
    user=User(id=userSchema.id,name=userSchema.name)
    sessionLocal().add(user)
    sessionLocal().commit()
    return user
```

When i try to run this API using UVICorn i was running successful and the table also created successfully but the data that i am sending through the body is not added in the table. 
The table is showing ***null*** value is added \

I have referred [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z1VV9aMoVbE&ab_channel=RedMeet)

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @anjaneyulubatta505 for help 
but we need to do below changes to post data in database

```
@app.post("/create-user")
def createUser(userSchema:UserSchema):
    user = User(id=userSchema.id, name=userSchema.name)
    with Session(bind=engine) as session:
        session.add(user)
        session.commit()
    return user
```

referred links

1. [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20201809/sqlalchemy-flask-attributeerror-session-object-has-no-attribute-model-chan)
2. [Link2](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_basics.html#opening-and-closing-a-session) from sqlAlChemy

Answer (score 0):

You are not committing the change to the database. Just change your code like below to make it work.

```py
# ... imports and other stuff
from DatabaseConnection import sessionLocal

@app.post("/create-user")
def createUser(userSchema:UserSchema):
    user = User(id=userSchema.id, name=userSchema.name)
    with sessionLocal() as session:
        session.add(user)
        session.commit()

    return user
```

Comment: Thanks for respond, but with the above code I am getting _500:Internal Server Error_

Comment: It giving me _sqlalchemy.exc.UnboundExecutionError: Could not locate a bind configured on mapper mapped class User->users, SQL expression or this Session._ error msg

Comment: @PiyushJiwane updated the code. you can check it now. make sure you imoprt localSession correctly.

Comment: Hi, still getting same error

Comment: I found a solution and we need to do below changes
`with Session(bind=engine) as session:`